# Ruby gem for sending emails after a contact form is filled

Tags: php, ruby, email, nanoc

I am using to nanoc to create a static website. We have a form in their, which i would like to be emailed once filled. Is there a way to do that ?is there a ruby gem for that ? or php any other easy  solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Is [pony](http://rubygems.org/gems/pony) what you're looking for?

Comment: no i am looking something else. does not have to be ruby. something that is easy to setup php will do too

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where are you hosting your website, if it allows you to execute PHP scripts, then in your form just put as an action a PHP script somewhere, and just receive the data via the $POST variable. PHP already has a function to send email.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Its pretty simple to use. Problem being that if you send too much from a non email account (as you can put whatever you want in the From: header) some emails like Gmail or so may tag your mail as spam.

The script can be on a different hosting or domain, but then you'll encounter some security issues.